# how to pass argument to multiple lambda expressions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

can i give 2 argumens if there is multiple lambda funcionts in javascripts?
i have the following code

```
var twice = (x) => {
  return x *x;
}

var lambda = (b) => { 
  (a) =>{
    return b(b(a));
  }
}; 


console.log(lambda(twice, 5));
```

this wont work, and
I could use

```
  var lambda = (b,a) => { 
        return b(b(a));
    };
```

and will work, but can I use separate lambda expression and give them arguments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You would take advantage of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) so that the inner function returned from invoking `lambda()` can keep a reference to its surrounding lexical environment.

You then call said inner function with the desired value `lambda(twice)(5)`, in this case, `5`.

```js
var twice = (x) => {
  return x *x;
}

var lambda = (b) => { 
  return (a) => {
    return b(b(a));
  }
}; 


console.log( lambda(twice)(5) ); // -> 625
```

Comment: thanks, I should thought of returning the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

You can forward arguments to a function like this:

```js
const twice = x => x * x;

const invokeFunctionWithArgs = (fn, ...args) => fn(...args);

console.log(invokeFunctionWithArgs(twice, 5)); // 25
```

Comment: Not the same result as OP calling `b(b(a))`

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood what the asker was trying to communicate.